# foreman start error (server.rb:33, missing argument...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, thin, foreman

After trying to start foreman, I get this error (note that it does seem to work on heroku though so I guess this is a strictly local problem):

```
hrn039:textthechange jon$ foreman start
02:20:00 web.1     | started with pid 7363
02:20:01 web.1     | /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!': missing argument: -e (OptionParser::MissingArgument)
02:20:01 web.1     |    from /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:280:in `parse_options'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:180:in `options'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:54:in `set_environment'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:42:in `initialize'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `new'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from /Users/jon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from script/rails:6:in `require'
02:20:01 web.1     |    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
02:20:01 web.1     | process terminated
02:20:01 system    | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

The Procfile only has one line as [specified by heroku](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3)

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

And my gemfile has

```
gem 'thin'
```

Google isn't being very helpful with this error.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file which specifies `$RACK_ENV` in your project?

Comment: Have you a RAKC_ENV define in your heroku app ? `heroku config`

Answer (score 21):

This is not about executing on Heroku - see that the original question about is about executing with Foreman - which is local execution.

You can replicate your error by executing the following:

> rails server thin -e

That's effectively what Foreman is running, given your Procfile:

> web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV

So I'm going to guess that you're not passing in an argument to -e.  ie. you haven't defined RACK_ENV locally.

What you can do is create a `.env` file in your local directory, something like

> RACK_ENV=development
>
> PORT=3000

Foreman will automatically pick up the local `.env` file and set the environment appropriately, before creating the process based on your process type declaration.

Comment: Note: If you're using foreman on production then you don't want to commit the .env file to your code repository. In that case, I suggest adding .env to your .gitignore file (assuming you're using git for version control).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with rails v3.2 in Ubuntu 10.04.
I managed to get thin running by doing the following steps:

1. Change your Procfile as follows:

   web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e development
2. Add `$stdout.sync = true` on the top of your config.ru file, to direct server output to your terminal (otherwise you do not get output in your terminal)

Tell me if it works!

Comment: If you have your Procfile with `-e development` then it's not going to work properly on Heroku where `-e production` should be used. You need to use `-e $RACK_ENV` and specify `RACK_ENV=development` in a `.env` file in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem.  If you change your Procfile to just

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT
```

it should work.  Note, this uses the default Thin port of 5000 rather than 3000 (which means you'll need to go to http://localhost:5000 to see your app.

Having just

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin
```

in your Procfile will use port 3000, but this will cause errors on Heroku.